# No me funciona si no pongo la imagen manual porque?

Tags: c++, qt

```
void MainWindow::on_tableView_clicked(const QModelIndex &index)
{
    if(!index.isValid()){
        return;
    }
    btnEdit->setEnabled(true);
    btnDelete->setEnabled(true);
    btnSave->setEnabled(true);
    btnImg->setEnabled(true);
    tableView->setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView::SelectRows);
    QString id=mModel->data(mModel->index(index.row(),0)).toString();

    QSqlQuery q;
    q.exec("SELECT id_elemento, id_grupo, id_tipo, nombre, descripcion, icono FROM elemento WHERE id_elemento= '" + id +"' ;");
    qDebug()<<id;
    q.first();
    qDebug() << q.lastError();
    lineCod->setText(q.value(0).toString());
    lineGroup->setText(q.value(1).toString());
    lineType->setText(q.value(2).toString());
    lineName->setText(q.value(3).toString());
    textDescription->setPlainText(q.value(4).toString());
    lineImg->setText(q.value(5).toByteArray());
    QPixmap pixmap;
    if(!pixmap.loadFromData(q.value(5).toByteArray())){
        labelImg->setText("<b>Error de Imagen</b>");
        return;
    }
    labelImg->setScaledContents(true);
    int w = labelImg->width();
    int h = labelImg->height();

    w=200;
    h=100;

    labelImg->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Maximum, QSizePolicy::Maximum);
    labelImg->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
    labelImg->setPixmap(pixmap.scaled(w,h,Qt::KeepAspectRatio));



}

void MainWindow::on_toolButton_clicked()
{
    imagenAdr=QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,"Escojer Icono",QDir::rootPath(),"*png");
    QFile archivo(imagenAdr);
    if(!archivo.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)){
        QMessageBox::critical(this,"Error",archivo.errorString());
        return;
    }
    lineImg->setText(imagenAdr);

    labelImg->setScaledContents(true);
    int w = labelImg->width();
    int h = labelImg->height();
    w=200;
    h=100;

    labelImg->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Maximum, QSizePolicy::Maximum);
    labelImg->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
    labelImg->setPixmap(QPixmap(imagenAdr).scaled(w,h,Qt::KeepAspectRatio));



}

void MainWindow::on_btnEdit_clicked()

{



    QFile archivo(lineImg->text());
    if(!archivo.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)){
        QMessageBox::critical(this,"Error",archivo.errorString());

        return;
    }



    mElemento=Elemento(lineCod->text(),(lineGroup->text()).toInt(),(lineType->text()).toInt(),
                       lineName->text(),textDescription->toPlainText(),archivo.readAll());

    QMessageBox::StandardButton reply;
    reply=QMessageBox::question(this,"Cancelar",
                                "¿Está seguro de que desea actualizar el valor de el elemento especificado de la base de datos?",
                                QMessageBox::Yes | QMessageBox::No);
    if(reply==QMessageBox::No){
        QMessageBox::information(this,"Cancelado","Ha cancelado la actualización del elemento");
    }

    if(reply==QMessageBox::Yes){
        QMessageBox::information(this,"Aprobado","Ha actualizado el elemento");
        if(!elem->editarElemento(mElemento)){

            return;
        }



    archivo.close();

      cargar();
      btnSave->setEnabled(true);
      btnDelete->setEnabled(true);
      btnImg->setEnabled(true);
      btnEdit->setEnabled(true);
    }
}

bool Elemento::editarElemento( Elemento &elemento)
{
    QString id=elemento.idElemento();
    int gru=elemento.idGrupo();
    int tip=elemento.idTipo();
    QString nom=elemento.nombre();
    QString des=elemento.descripcion();
    QByteArray icono=elemento.icono();


QSqlQuery q;
        q.prepare("UPDATE elemento SET id_elemento=:id, id_grupo=:grupo, id_tipo=:tipo,  nombre=:nombre, descripcion=:descripcion, icono=:icono WHERE id_elemento='"+id+"';");
        q.bindValue(":id", id);
        q.bindValue(":grupo",gru);
        q.bindValue(":tipo", tip);
        q.bindValue(":nombre",nom);
        q.bindValue(":descripcion", des);
        q.bindValue(":icono",icono);

        q.exec();


    bool ok=q.exec();
    if(!ok){

      QSqlError mError=q.lastError().text();
      qDebug()<<mError;


    }
    return ok;



}
```

Resumen-> Si la imagen la saco de la tabla me da error al editar, pero si la meto manualmente funciona todo perfectamente. Supongo que al cargar el lineImg desde la tabla algo esta incorrecto.

Comment: la tabla contiene el binario de la imagen o solamente su nombre??

Comment: contiene un byteArray de la imagen,

Comment: a ver si me entero... ¿estás diciendo que la línea que no funciona es `lineImg->setText(q.value(5).toByteArray());`?

Comment: si ejecuto on_toolButton_clicked() y escojo una imagen funciona. Pero si ejecuto solo MainWindow::on_tableView_clicked(const QModelIndex &index) lo que me carga en el lineEdit no me funciona

Comment: El origen del problema aquí pueden ser variopinto. Puede ser que el campo de la base de datos sea incorrecto y estropee el contenido de la imagen, que es contenido binario. ¿El campo es de tipo BLOB o TEXT?

Comment: es de tipo bytea, y me carga bien en el label la imagen desde la tabla. el problema radica al devolver la imagen del label a la base de datos, que no me la acepta

Comment: Es peligroso asumir que un campo de texto va a mostrar correctamente contenido binario... quizás deberías hacer la prueba de obtener el `byteArray` de una imagen leída de fichero y la equivalente leída de la base de datos y hacer una comparación byte a byte para garantizar que los datos sean los mismos (y chequear también la longitud de ambos buffers)

Comment: ?PNG me devuelve el mismo valor en el contenido del lineImg de las dos maneras si hago un qDebug()

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59370/discussion-between-eferion-and-antonio-veloso-gomez).

Comment: No se donde escribir en el chat

Comment: Pincha en el enlace y el campo para escribir se encuentra en el pie de página

Comment: En cualquier caso te pongo aquí el comentario (lo borraré en unas horas): "qDebug no.... primero comprobar que el size() es el mismo y después iterar con un for y comparar byte a byte... si se detectan dos bytes distintos es que el guardado no está bien hecho"